# Adapt standalone application to use Spring

Tags: java, spring, swing

I've read about how to use Spring in standalone applications but I'm not sure what should be the approach for refactoring a large code base of 120,000 lines for making the change as gradual as possible.

As far as I understand Spring won't inject anything in an object unless that object is managed by the application context. If this is true, I think I have two choices:
1- Start refactoring from the main class down, but this means complicated scenarios will appear soon.
2- Share the application context statically so that I can start refactoring the simplest things, scalating in difficulty when I'm ready.

I'm not a fan of static access so I would try to avoid that choice, but I don't know if it's a good idea to start with the huge classes that are loaded at startup. Any ideas of the best approach?

By the way, is it OK to inject Swing components until I can fix the dependencies?

Comment: How does your current project work? Is it a web app? Another standalone app without Spring?

Comment: @Desorder: The project is a standalone Swing application without Spring.

Comment: You could add lil block of code to start up the String container. From that you can slowly make pieces of code to become managed by Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that before approaching such a big technology change, it may be a good idea to start asking yourself if you are following the architecture that Spring guides you to have when you start using it from the beginning. 
Therefore, is your application based on the [MVC pattern](http://blog.iandavis.com/2008/12/09/what-are-the-benefits-of-mvc/)?

- If not, maybe your product is not yet ready for being refactored to
  use Spring. In this case, I would suggest refactoring the product
  design first, so that it complies with the MVC architectural pattern.
- If yes, then I would proceed with a use-case-based approach, starting
  from the use cases that required a complicated design and
  implementation.

E.g. I would look for very important entity classes or business classes containing a lot of logic. This way, you can reduce the risk of doing a lot of refactoring before realizing that, for example, Spring is not a good fit for the core of your product.
After identifying the most critical use case, you can start to experiment how refactoring works on your current product by introducing Spring from end to end on a single critical scenario (user input - business logic - entity manipulation - persistence). If you are successful, then you keep refactoring, otherwise you can go back and try to understand where you need to change your current product before introducing Spring.

Of course, this works when you have some experience with Spring and you do not have to cope with newcomer's issues. If you are new to Spring, then I would recommend getting some experience with Spring before starting the adventure of refactoring such a big project.

Answer (score 2):

Start simply and wire new code/class with spring. You'll amend your existing main method to initialise the ApplicationContext and load your new feature. Over time then as change requests arrive you'll refactor and migrate the existing codebase to use spring dependency injection.